# Jquery UI: Selecting a selectable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm building an app using javascript that pulls images from S3 via the AWS api. I employed jquery_ui to add select functionality to the app ui. Currently I can select the images that I've loaded via s3 in my gallery with no problem, based on the jquery ui documentation. However, I have a sidebar navigation panel that allows me to select the file names, and I want the image in the gallery to also appear selected.

I've tried `$(#image-id).addClass('ui-selected')` and various other iterations of the same concept but nothing happens.

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong? I can't claim to be a JS expert.

HTML:

```
<div class="right-container">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <input type="file" id="file-chooser" name="files[]" multiple />
            <button id="upload-button">Upload</button>
            <div id="results"></div>
            <ul id="objects"></ul>
        </div>

        <div class="navigation">
            <div id="item-status"></div>
            <ul id="selectable-items">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="content">
            <div id="image-status"></div>
            <ul id="selectable-images">
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div id="details">
            <ul id="properties"></ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Relevant JS to display images:

```
// Display images from s3
$(document).ready(function(){
function listImages(){
    s3.listObjects(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            $('#image-status').html('Could not load objects from S3');
        } else {
            $('#image-status').html('<h3>Loaded ' + data.Contents.length + ' images from ' + bucket + '.</h3>');
            for (var i = 0; i < data.Contents.length; i++) {
                $('#selectable-images').append("<li><img id=" + data.Contents[i].Key + " src='" + origin + bucket + "/" + data.Contents[i].Key + "'>" + "</img></li>");
            }
        }
    });
}

// Selectable images
$( "#selectable-images" ).selectable({
    filter: "img",
    selected: function(event, ui) {
// Get image properties
        if($(ui.selected).attr('id') != null) {
            var file = $(ui.selected).attr('id');
            selected_image = {Key: file};
        }

// Display image properties
        s3.headObject(selected_image, function(err, data) {
            if(err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack)
            } else {
                properties = data
            }
            $('#properties').html("<li>Key: " + $(ui.selected).attr('id') + "</li> " + "<li>Content Type: " + properties.ContentType + "</li> " + "<li>Last Modified: " + properties.LastModified + "</li>")
        });
    }
});
});
```

JSBin: http://jsbin.com/fodovoko/2/edit?html,css,js,console,output

Comment: Is #image-status ever set?

Comment: Initially? No, it's just an empty div. Is that relevant? I'm not interacting with that at all.

Comment: Mby not, it is just that this is too little to be able to work with.

Comment: Is there anything I can add that would help out? I threw up some more code. Essentially I'm just pulling images from s3. Using jquery-ui to make them `selectable`. Right now I'm simply trying to add a class to the `<img>` based on the `id` using my browser console before writing the full functionality. Can't get it to add a class to the `<img>` however.

Comment: It is just that I can't see the code where you are adding the mentioned class to the image.

Comment: I'd say that's not wholly relevant either, since regardless of what I'm doing in the script, I can't add a class to the element that I need to add a class to. I'll try to throw up some code approx to what I'm trying to do, however.

In the browser console I'm trying `$(#image-id).addClass('ui-selected')`, which works on every other element, but not that one I'm trying to effect.

Comment: you know, without fiddle it is hard to say. 1. Are you sure that your code where you are adding the class to that element is acctually firing? 2. Are you sure that the id selector is correct? 3. Are you sure that the class is not added but you just do not see the result (for whatever reason)? ... this can't be solved easily like this. Just create fiddle and I will look at it.

Comment: Okay, added a quick JSBin of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: OF COURSE it was something silly.

The id of the element I was trying to add a class to has a '.', which I didn't escape.

`$('#image_6//.jpg').addClass('ui-selected')` works.

Comment: Well, my 2. point was correct then :) glad it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the selector string contains any meta-characters, they must be escaped with two backslash characters. The meta-characters are !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~

For example, if your id value is "image_6.jpg", your selector will need to be "#image_6\\.jpg".